# Is there a method within q-layout to scroll to top in quasar?

Tags: quasar

I have a q-layout (just a simple one as below) within a q-dialog where I need to scroll top of the page when a certain process is completed.

```
    <q-dialog v-model="is_form_dialog_open">
        <q-layout view="hhh LpR fff" container ref="scroll_area" id="top" style="max-height: 1200px: width: 1200px; max-width: 1200px;" class="bg-white shadow-3 rounded-borders">
            <q-header elevated class="bg-grey-3 text-black">
                <q-toolbar>
                    <q-toolbar-title> Add </q-toolbar-title>
                </q-toolbar>
            </q-header>
            <q-page-container class="row q-ma-sm">
                ...
            </q-page-container>
            <q-footer elevated class="bg-grey-2 text-white">
                <q-toolbar class="justify-end q-pa-sm q-gutter-sm">
                    <q-btn label="Test" @click="test()" color="primary" />  
                </q-toolbar>
            </q-footer>
        </q-layout>
    </q-dialog>
```

There is a component q-page-scroller easily scrolls to top of the layout but it uses a clicked. I need a way where I can trigger this (scroll to top) via method. Is there a method to scroll to the top of the q-layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is a method:

```
...
methods: {
   GoToTop() {
       window.scrollTo(0, 0);
   },
...
```

coupled to a button :

```
<q-btn icon="open_in_browser" @click="GoToTop()" />
```

Comment: I already tried that, unfortunately without any luck. Somehow it doesn't work within the dialog and layout.

Comment: if you have dialog, then you have to use setTimeout(function () {
                    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
                }, 200);

Answer (score 1):

I use this code from [here](https://quasar.dev/quasar-utils/scrolling-utils#Scrolling-to-an-element) to scroll to top. Just call the method with your header element as el.

```
import { scroll } from 'quasar'
const { getScrollTarget, setScrollPosition } = scroll // takes an element 

object function scrollToElement (el) { 
       const target = getScrollTarget(el)
       const offset = el.offsetTop const duration = 1000 setScrollPosition(target, offset, duration) 
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks for directing me to the correct documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**My two cents for OP's question**.

1. `stores/ui.js` Create Pinia store for shared UI states and methods.

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useUI = defineStore('ui-store', {
  actions: {
    setScrollPosition: (axis = 'vertical', offset = 0, duration = 0) => null,
  },
})
```

2. `layouts/MainLayout.vue` Create your layout and wrap it with `q-scroll-area` component

```js
<template>
  <q-layout>
    <q-scroll-area
      ref="scrollPageRef"
      style="height: 100vh">
      <q-page-container>
        <router-view />
      </q-page-container>
    </q-scroll-area>
  </q-layout>
</template>
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
import { useUI } from 'stores/ui'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MainLayout',
  setup () {
    const ui = useUI()
    const scrollPageRef = ref(null)

    ui.$onAction(({ name, args }) => {
      switch (name) {
        case 'setScrollPosition':
          scrollPageRef.value.setScrollPosition(args[0], args[1], args[2])
      }
    })
    return {
      scrollPageRef,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

3. `components/SomeComponent.vue` Create the component from where you want to call scoll action.

```js
<template>
  <q-page-sticky position="bottom-right" :offset="[18, 18]">
    <q-btn @click="scrollToTop" fab icon="keyboard_arrow_up" />
  </q-page-sticky>
</template>
<script>
import { useUI } from 'stores/ui'
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'BackToTopComponent',
  setup () {
    const ui = useUI()
    const scrollToTop = () =>{
      ui.setScrollPosition('vertical', 0, 250)
    }
    return {
      scrollToTop,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

4. `pages/SomePage.vue` Create your page

```js
<template>
  <q-page>
    <div id="some-page-content"></div>
    <some-component/>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import SomeComponent from 'components/SomeComponent.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'SomePage',
  components: {
    SomeComponent,
  },
})
</script>
<style scoped>
#some-page-content {
  height: 500vh;
}
</style>
```

5. `router/routes.js` add your route

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/test',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: () => import('pages/SomePage.vue'),
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Comment: All these, just to scroll to top?

Comment: `ui.setScrollPosition('vertical', 0, 250)` example shows usage to top since thats OP question, however you can modify behaviour by changing these 3 arguments 1. “axis” with values either “horizontal” or “vertical”, 2. argument is offset and 3. arg is duration of scroll animation to scroll to your axis and ofset location. If thats what you are asking. So `ui.setScrollPosition('vertical', 100, 250)`  would scroll 100px from top

Comment: You know, the my people used to say, *don't cross the river to fetch water...*

Answer (score 0):

If you have **dialog**, then you have to use setTimeout function

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
}, 200);
```